# How do I embed a url in flash?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I am using flash CS5 and am wondering how to embed a website.  I am creating a mobile html5 website on my pc and want to embed it in flash.  I want to be able to navigate to it in the swf (I don't want the url to open in my browser).  How do I do this in flash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How do I do this in flash?

You don't. Standalone Flash player or browser plugin cannot show *arbitrary* HTML. There is `Label` control in Flex, but it only knows a few basic tags. Only AIR has `HtmlLoader` control which exposes Webkit compatible browser.

Answer (score 1):

this approach that you desire is the complete opposite of what's common with browser-resident Flash.

however, if accomplishing this is absolutely necessary what you could do is publish your .swf with transparency, creating a section of the .swf to form a kind of cut-out window  that exposes the the html wrapper below, then make an ExternalInterface call to the wrapper to load html content under the .swf.  this would require that the site you want to load is apart of the .swf's html wrapper.

the above approach i've mentioned is seriously ghetto and you probably shouldn't do it, but i just wanted to let you know that it is possible if it's absolutely necessary.